# Spring Data JDBC Custom Naming Strategy

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Is there any way to change the default column naming strategy for a referenced entity then the default (name of the class).  The docs say to call the method `setForeignKeyNaming(ForeignKeyNaming.IGNORE_RENAMING)` on `RelationalMappingContext`'s NamingStrategy. However, this method is only available on the implementation `DefaultNamingStrategy` and `JdbcMappingContext`'s naming strategy but it is package private (CachingNamingStrategy). Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JensSchauder sorry I didn’t know you could do that

Comment: Don't worry and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Bean // in some config class
public JdbcMappingContext jdbcMappingContext() {
    DefaultNamingStrategy namingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy();
    namingStrategy.setForeignKeyNaming(ForeignKeyNaming.IGNORE_RENAMING);
    return new JdbcMappingContext(namingStrategy);
}
```

And instead of the default plural camelcase class name as a foreign key, name it whatever you want. Just make sure the field has the same name.