# DataJdbcTest Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I asked and answered a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76626673/spring-data-jdbc-custom-naming-strategy?noredirect=1#comment135125473_76626673) that has now come back to bite me. Unfortunately, this only works with `@SpringBootTest` which loads the entire application context and causes an error when I use the following configuration:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJdbcTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

Spring throws an error because it assumes I am using the default naming strategy when naming my columns. I also using postgres instead of H2  Is their any way for me to get spring to load that single custom configuration or do I have to revert back to speed up my tests? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of `DataJdbcTest` says

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration, scan for `AbstractJdbcConfiguration` subclasses, and apply only configuration relevant to Data JDBC tests.

So having a `AbstractJdbcConfiguration` which applies the `NamingStrategy` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. I was using SpringBootTest and when I switched to DataJDBCTest I didn’t know I had to add it. I fixed it with an import in the relevant tests.